# how to break append break line using dom manipulation

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sty.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="'style1">harshs</h1>
        <br>
        <div id='numbers' class="numbersstyle"></div>
    
        <div id="dom">
        </div >
        
        <div id="button">

        </div>
        <script src="jssty/jessy.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
let k = document.getElementById('dom')
let bu = document.getElementById('button')
let num = document.getElementById('numbers')
let i = []
let harsha = () => {
    let l = Math.random() * 90;
    i.push(Math.floor(l))
    let m = document.createElement('h1')
    m.textContent = Math.floor(l)
    k.appendChild(m)
}

for (let i = 1; i <= 90; i++) {
    let h = document.createElement('p')
    h.textContent = i;
    num.appendChild(h)
    if (i % 10 == 0) {
        let li = document.createElement('br')
        num.append(li)
    }
}
let but = document.createElement('button')
but.textContent = 'click'
bu.appendChild(but)
but.addEventListener('click', harsha)
k.classList
```

I'm expecting a line break after every 10th element. After running this code I can see there is a <br> tag appended to numbers container. However, it's not reflecting in the web page.

What is the solution for this or what is the reason for this mistake?

Comment: The line break tag is working normally in my side without the sty.css. Maybe that is causing the problem. Could you include related css into your question?